# Pass array values to another script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an issue where I need to access variables from one script in another. I've searched this question and I understand that we can use import to access variables in another script. The data is coming from an Arduino and is sent to a Raspberry Pi via serial and the values are continuous until the script is stopped. I have put my code into a function and I need to return the sensor data continuously.

`values.py` script:

```
import datetime
import serial
datetime.datetime.now()
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)

def printVal():
    while True:
        read_serial=ser.readline()
        val= read_serial.decode()
        val =val.strip()
        row = [x for x in val.split(' ')]
        if len(row) == 6:
            #p = ('Sensor1:',row[0], 'Sensor2:',row[1], 'Sensor3:',row[2], 'Sensor4:',row[3], 'Sensor5:',row[4], 'Sensor6:',row[5])
            #print (row)
            #return row
            sensor1= row[0]
            sensor2 = row[1]
            sensor3 = row[2]
            sensor4 = row[3]
            sensor5 = row[4]
            sensor6 = row[5]
            #print (sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, sensor4, sensor5, sensor6)
            return (sensor1)
printVal()
```

`second.py` script:

```
from values import printVal
print (printVal())
```

I need to include the `if len(row)==6` statement because the first line that prints will be three values and the other values will be out of the index.

My question is how would I access each individual array value in the second script. Would I need to print the function, I am confused on how to do this. I think the return statement is causing only one value to print and not be continuous.

Comment: essentially, look at it this way. your second script only receives whatever you return from the function. If you want the list, you have to return it, and assign that return to a variable.

Comment: `return row` was OK. Note that *printVal* name is misleading.

Comment: And why `return row` didn't work?

Comment: return row did work, but how would I get it to run continuously until the script is stopped? If I were to just print row in my values.py then the data from the sensors is continous but when I use return and print in second.py it only prints one line only.

Comment: Call it in a loop?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the json format to pass a single variable, an array, a hashmap.

For continuous transmisssion, you can read the data line by line and decode/load the data once a line is completed.

The documentation with examples :

- python2 https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
- python3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score -1):

You can return a dictionary from your printVal() function.

```
def printVal():

    # your logic here to get sensor data

    sensor_data = {'sensor1': row[0],
        'sensor2': row[1],
        'sensor3': row[2],
        'sensor4': row[3],
        'sensor5': row[4],
        'sensor6': row[5]
         }
    return sensor_data
```

Then you can assign the return values to a variable in your second script like so:

```
from values import printVal

sensor_data = printVal()
print(sensor_data['sensor1'])
print(sensor_data['sensor6'])
```